# Get CPU core id executing a process which suddenly exits

Tags: linux, process, cpu, top, smp

In Linux, in a multi-core processor, [`ps`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5736891), [`top`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32640560) and similar tools can show the CPU logical core id running a specific process. If the process runs for a certain amount of time, it's easy to identify it in the process list.

I have instead a stand-alone program which prints "hello world" and the number of logical core detected from CPU assembly (`RDPID` instruction):

```
$ ./hello_world
hello world
1
$
```

It immediately ends. I would like to compare this number with the one provided by `ps`, `top` or similar. So, how to obtain the same information (the CPU logical core id) in this case? How to get the process information while this process is still executing?

Comment: Why is this information important in case of a short-living process? Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski This could be useful in general. However, I edited the question adding more details.

Comment: I don't see where `top` shows the CPU "running" a process or thread. If a process is using 10% of a CPU, then 90% of the time *no* CPU is running it. `top` can show you the "Last used CPU", but with a warning that even asking is likely to alter the outcome across the whole system. For `ps`, the thread cumulative CPU time is found from the time between entry and exit of user mode (not continuously updated). CFS deals with variable time-slices, and longest appears to be capped at 0.006 secs, which means any separate process attempting to monitor is hopelessly lagging behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the Linux syscall [`getcpu`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcpu.2.html), which returns the CPU that the thread was scheduled on at the point it made the syscall.

Read the notes on that man page and realize how right Paul is: making a syscall gives you a relatively high probability that you will be scheduled on a different CPU core the moment it returns. So, getcpu only makes guaranteed statements on your thread's CPU core at a point in time in the past. Not the present.

So, long story short:

> How to get the process information while this process is still executing?

You can get that the CPU core running a thread using `getcpu`, but it's immediately outdated information. Core allocation isn't static.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment of a process to a core id is transient (unless specifically locked), and the tools can only show the instantaneous value.

A thread can be rescheduled onto a different core at any time (generally during a system call, or when it exceeds its time slice). A multi-threaded process can be running on many cores simultaneously.

There may be optimisations which try to maintain some stability (e.g. to improve caching), but they cannot be relied on.

Also, `echo` is a shell built-in -- it "runs" inside the existing shell process.

Comment: I edited the question mentioning a stand-alone example process. There's no problem if the core id is transient. But is there a way to obtain this transient value while the process is executing?